# Life of PID in windows

Tags: vb.net, process, pid

Can any one please tell me about the life of a Process Identification (PID) in Windows Server.

Does it remain same for a long process, I mean after a day or two?

I am saving PIDs in my application and want to evaluate the process on the basis of their IDs.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Please don't use backticks for non-code - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't change as long as the process is still running.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/07/10112755.aspx

If you shut down the program, or kill it, and then restart it, you will get a new process id.

If you start the program you can use Process.WaitForExit. If you are starting the programs, I'd start each process in a new thread and use Process.WaitForExit.

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

For a different process check out the following website: http://alperguc.blogspot.ca/2008/11/c-process-processgetprocessesbyname.html

It shows how to find a process and attach to it's Exited event.

Comment: is it possible to get process details at its exit handler. Kindly help me, how to get process info (name and pid) when it is going to kill.

Comment: If you start the program you can use Process.WaitForExit.  If you are starting the programs, I'd start each process in a new thread and use Process.WaitForExit.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

Comment: For a different process check out the following website:  http://alperguc.blogspot.ca/2008/11/c-process-processgetprocessesbyname.html  It shows how to find a process and attach to it's Exited event.